# Path and context conflicting in flutter

Tags: flutter

I have used the path package and when I try to use it I get error 'The argument type 'Context' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext''. Could anyone help me with this? In my code when I am trying to get my token and call AlertDialog box, the context there gives the error saying 'The argument type 'Context' can't be assigned to the parameter type 'BuildContext''.

```
 String? token =
        await Provider.of<AuthenticationController>(context, listen: false)
            .getToken();



  Future<bool> _onWillPop() async {
    return (await showDialog(
          context:  context,
          builder: ( context) => AlertDialog(
            title: const Text('Are you sure?'),
            // content: Text('Do you want to exit an App'),
            actions: <Widget>[
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                  Navigator.push(
                      context,
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                          builder: (context) => BasicBooksCategory(
                              basicBookId: widget.basicBookId)));
                },
                child: const Text('Yes'),
              ),
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pop(context);
                },
                child: const Text('No'),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        )) ??
        false;
  }
```

Comment: You code is insufficient. Please provide the code from where you are getting the context. It might be different context that you are calling without giving more code can't tell.

Answer (score 1):

there is two issue
1: There was some conflict with importing 'package:path/path.dart'. So after putting an alias in it like this: import 'package:path/path.dart' as Path
2: using this.context instead of context or BuildContext(context)yourcode

Comment: it is works for me